# Lion login screen when using two screens

Tags: macos, customization

When logging into Lion with a second screen attached, does the second screen always have a plain grey background as opposed to the textured background that the primary screen has?

Is there a way to change the login wallpaper on only the second screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is "no". You can select a custom desktop picture for Lion, but I know of no way to select different pictures for each screen.

Comment: But actually I don't even ask for a different one for the other screen: the default texture would be fine. That's really strange Lion is so bad with two screens...